# Cordova WebView TIMEOUT ERROR with android

Tags: android, cordova, android-webview

I am trying a simple application where I want to display my mobile website inside a native wrapper in android. I am following the documentation where the only change I am making is with loadUrl where instead of loading the CordovaWebView with index.html from assets folder, I will  be pointing it to a mobile website, say https://www.google.com

The webview app comes up but there isn a CordovaWebView TIMEOUT ERROR received. following are the snippets from my code

```
public class CordovaWebViewActivity extends Activity implements CordovaInterface{

    private CordovaWebView webView;
    private static final String TAG = "CORDOVA_WEBVIEW_ACTIVITY";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cordova_web_view);

        webView = (CordovaWebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");


    }

   @Override
   public Activity getActivity() {
    return this;
   }
   //... other overrided methods from interface
}
```

and when I run the code, I get the following error in my console DDMS

```
07-31 20:56:08.737: D/dalvikvm(2016): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 42K, 6% free 2780K/2928K, paused 23ms, total 25ms
07-31 20:56:08.746: I/dalvikvm-heap(2016): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.887MB for 1127536-byte allocation
07-31 20:56:08.777: D/dalvikvm(2016): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 4% free 3879K/4032K, paused 36ms, total 36ms
07-31 20:56:08.836: D/CordovaWebView(2016): CordovaWebView is running on device made by: unknown
07-31 20:56:08.836: D/JsMessageQueue(2016): Set native->JS mode to 2
07-31 20:56:08.996: D/gralloc_goldfish(2016): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
07-31 20:56:09.376: E/cutils-trace(2016): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-31 20:56:09.687: D/TilesManager(2016): Starting TG #0, 0x2a26cc40
07-31 20:56:28.874: E/CordovaWebView(2016): CordovaWebView: TIMEOUT ERROR!
```

I have config.xml in my /res/xml folder that has the following

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.helloCordova" version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets">
    <name>Hello Cordova</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <feature name="App">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App" />
    </feature>
    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="useBrowserHistory" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
</widget>
```

and i also have a cordova.xml in my /res/xml folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<cordova>

    <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> <!-- allow local pages -->
    <access origin="https://www.google.com" />


    <log level="DEBUG"/>
    <preference name="useBrowserHistory" value="false" />
</cordova>
```

Please help what am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: have you found the solution. I facing same problem. please share

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong, the *TIMEOUT ERROR* probably occurs because your Android phone (or your emulator) runs too slow.

You can try to increase the load timeout with the following instruction :

```
super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);
```

in your OnCreate method. Or set it in the config.xml file :

```
<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="60000" />
```

Comment: so, I have the same error, I mean almost the same. I have the website loading with all it content, but after some time later I have this TIMEOUT ERROR coming in. With your modification, it became better but haven't gone. Could you tell me why this happning at all, even after page successful loading?

Comment: Ok, now my app loaded, but loading process was very long. How can I find the reason of this?

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer is

```
<preference name="LoadUrlTimeoutValue" value="60000"/> - capital 'L'
```